# jQuery getelementsbyclassname equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementsbyclassname

I have written a lot of JavaScript code using getElementsByClass name and now realised this is not supported in IE8 so am trying to swap them all for the jQuery equivalent.

My code runs without errors using

```
   div1.getElementsByClassName("div2");
```

however if I swap this line for

```
   $(".div1 .div2");
```

my code produces an error "Uncaught NotFoundError: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist."

What is the difference between the JavaScript code and jQuery code that could make the code behave differently?

Comment: Can you replicate it in a fiddle? What you have should work..

Comment: Are you using the version of jQuery which does not support IE8?

Comment: That error pops up when you try to use native methods on a jQuery object (in certain cases), so the issue isn't the selector, that is correct, it's how you're trying to use it.

Comment: Try using `$(".div1 .div2").get()` and see what happens, or rewrite your script to work with jQuery objects, and not DOM nodes.

Comment: I am setting a variable equal to $(".div1 .div2") and trying to reference the second element in the DOM array with x[1] when I get the error

Comment: how would div1.getAnything work if div1 is a class? it needs to be an ID or a name in IE to work like that if I am not mistaken (cannot test that assumption right now on my mac)

Comment: damn you are right, it's not working because div1 is a class. what I need to do is get all div2s in the first instance of div1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've already written code using `getElementsByClassName`, you might be better off using a [shim](https://gist.github.com/E01T/6088383) or [polyfill](https://gist.github.com/eikes/2299607) so you don't have to rewrite existing code.

Unfortunately, most of the stuff out there only supplies `document.getElementsByClassName`, so if you're using it from other elements, <s>you'll have to roll your own</s> you can try this one I wrote a while back.

```
// getElementsByClassName polyfill
(function(){
    if (document.getElementsByClassName)
        return;
    if (!window.Element)
        throw "Can't polyfill getElementsByClassName";

    function gEBCN(className) {
        var all = this.getElementsByTagName("*"),
            rex = new RegExp("(?:\\s|^)" + className + "(?:\\s|$)"),
            out = [],
            element, i;
        for (i = all.length; i--;) {
            element = all[i];
            if (element.className.match(rex))
                out.unshift(element);
        }
        return out;
    }

    var el = window.Element.prototype;
    var doc = document.constructor.prototype;
    el.getElementsByClassName = doc.getElementsByClassName = gEBCN;
}());
```

This script checks if `document.getElementsByClassName` exists, and if it doesn't, it creates `document.getElementsByClassName` and `Element.prototype.getElementsByClassName` with equivalent functionality. Since all HTML elements have `Element.prototype` in their prototype chain, you'll be able to call `.getElementsByClassName` on any element, just as you can in any browser that has native support for the function. In other words, you can just drop this code at the top of your file or put it a separate file and include it, and then your current scripts should work in old IE and any other browsers that don't support  `.getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I wrote a gEBCN polyfill that worked for all elements at some point, let me poke around and see if I can find it.

Comment: is it just a case of pasting that code at the top of the js file? i don't understand any of that code

Comment: @Alex, yep, that's it, just paste it in at the top. I'll update the answer with a note about how it works.

Comment: thanks, getElementByClassName doesn't produce an error in IE8 anymore so I think your code worked. meant IE got further through the code and complained about insertBefore instead, I really should check compatibility of functions before I blindly use them.

Comment: @Alex, no problem. I think `insertBefore` works pretty much everywhere, so it's probably a problem with the way it's being used.

Comment: it was because IE8 errors when trying to insert before a null, other browsers ignore it

Comment: @Alex, glad you found it. Good old IE, ignoring [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-952280727) as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Note that jQuery 2.x does *[not](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/)* support IE6/7/8. This might be the problem. Instead, use the 1.x branch (for example version [[1.10.2]](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js)), which still supports those browsers.

When using a 1.x version of jQuery, the following should be the correct selector for what you want.

```
$(".div1 .div2") //or:
$(".div1").find(".div2") // or, if .div2 is a direct descendant:
$(".div1 > .div2")
```

Comment: I realised where I am going wrong is I want to get all instances of div2 in the first instance of div1. the javascript is x = document.getElementsByClassName("div1")[0]; y = x.getElementsByClassName("div2");

Comment: @Alex, if you have already written code like that, why not just support it with a polyfill instead of rewriting the code and trying to shoehorn it to fit into the context of a GP library? idgi.